# Rails: NoMethodError: private method `gem'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration, rubygems

When I run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` I get the following output:

```
NoMethodError: private method `gem' called for
<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007ffa0312c410>
rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing'
/config/application.rb:24:in `<class:Application>'
```

Versions

`gem 'rails', '4.2.6'`

`ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]`

Ive tried a different ruby version, a different rails version and rebuilding all my gems without any luck.

Comment: Is this a new repo? Also, can you post your application.rb?

Comment: Something isn't right in your `application.rb`. You should declare gems in your `Gemfile`, not there.

Comment: Yeah I had `config.gem "newrelic_rpm"` in my `application.rb`. This is an old repo not sure why it just started to fail